# In which form should the input and the label data be needed into Keras fit function?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train a sequential classifier, with 1 input neuron, 3 output neurons. The data is in data frames `X` and `Y`, but how must I feed this data into `fit` function in `keras` library? In other words, what should be the variable type of `train_x` and `train_y` (for example, is it data frame, matrix, list, etc)?

```
[...]

predictor <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 8, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(1)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 8, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 3, activation = "softmax")

[...]

train_x <- X
train_y <- Y

history <- predictor %>% fit(
  train_x,
  train_y,
  epochs = 20,
  verbose = 2
)
```

**Edit:**

If I can use dataframe, then how should I set `input_shape`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable type for `fit` should be of vector, matrix, or array.

As per the [documentation](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/fit.html), it states below,

> x -
>   Vector, matrix, or array of training data (or list if the model has multiple inputs). If all inputs in the model are named, you can also pass a list mapping input names to data. x can be NULL (default) if feeding from framework-native tensors (e.g. TensorFlow data tensors).
>
> y - Vector, matrix, or array of target (label) data (or list if the
>   model has multiple outputs). If all outputs in the model are named,
>   you can also pass a list mapping output names to data. y can be NULL
>   (default) if feeding from framework-native tensors (e.g. TensorFlow
>   data tensors).

The model needs to know what input shape it should expect. For this reason, the first layer in a sequential model (and only the first, because following layers can do automatic shape inference) needs to receive information about its input shape. Ex: You can pass a batch_size argument to a layer. If you pass both `batch_size=32` and `input_shape=c(6, 8)` to a layer, it will then expect every batch of inputs to have the batch shape `(32, 6, 8)`.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.